# Print Without Cell Fill Color But Keep Cell Text Color

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with 19 sheets in it.  The cells in the sheets are color coded to allow the user to know what is supposed to be edited.  When we print it, we're supposed to set the print area's cells with white.  I usually forget this step and have to reprint it.

Ideally, I would like to automate this process.  My attempts to find a solution have only suggested that I print the sheet in black and white.  This is not a solution that I want to use because the cell contents are also colored and I want them to stay that way when I print.

Is there a way that I can remove only the cell's fill color, print it, and have it revert back to the original formatting?  VBA options are fine.

Comment: You want the cell colors to be cleared when you print or stay colored? You say you "want them to stay that way" - and "then you want to "remove only the cell's fill color, print it"

Comment: @dbmitch I want the text to remain colored and the cell fill color to be white for all cells.

Comment: So each sheet has a print area pre-defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Usage:**

> ClearPrint "Sheet1"

```
Sub ClearPrint(WorksheetName)
    Sheets(WorksheetName).Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
    With Sheets(1).Cells.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Sheets(1).PrintOut
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets(1).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```